# Make textview scroll horizontally to left

Tags: android

I am developing a simple math calculator for Android. I want to know how I can make the textview scroll horizontally to the left when the input is long and has exceeded the textview width. I have tried using

```
android:ellipsize="Marquee"
```

But this will make the textview not showing inputs. I also tried:

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal" and
android:scrollhorizontally="true".
```

But none worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `TextView` inside `Horizontalscrollview`

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
      <TextView 
      .../>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```